# Send Ajax request to many server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have problem with my code:
Now I want to send request Ajax to 2 page, is it ok ? if ok, can show me how to do. Thanks.

Example:

```
function change_select_employee(){
  var p="";
  p="&month="+document.getElementById('F02S').value;

  document.getElementById('select_employee').innerHTML = "";
  new Ajax.Request('a.php',   { method:'get', onSuccess:onLoad_select ,parameters:p}); 
}
```

I want send this ajax to 2 file, a.php, b.php, how do I do it ?

Comment: simple, use ajax request twice :)

Comment: make an array of all the locations, and loop... that's the easiest way, if there is any other

Comment: because i don't know how to do, and I want to send once, and request will send 2 files, thanks all answers .

Answer (score 1):

As both comments suggest you can go both ways about this, either run the `Ajax.Request` twice or use an array to hold your target urls.

```
function change_select_employee(){
  var p = "&month="+document.getElementById('F02S').value;

  document.getElementById('select_employee').innerHTML = "";
  new Ajax.Request('a.php',   { method:'get', onSuccess:onLoad_select ,parameters:p}); 
  new Ajax.Request('b.php',   { method:'get', onSuccess:onLoad_select ,parameters:p}); 
}
```

or

```
function change_select_employee(){

  destinations = ["a.php","b.php"];

  var p = "&month="+document.getElementById('F02S').value;

  destinations.forEach(function(dest) {
    new Ajax.Request(dest,   { method:'get', onSuccess:onLoad_select ,parameters:p}); 
  });

  document.getElementById('select_employee').innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

You can even define the target url array outside the main function and pass it as an argument to `change_select_employee($destinations)`

Comment: oh, thank you, it works, but I just want sent request to a.php, b.php, but in file b.php, I use value from ajax in file b.php, is it ok ?

Comment: good to hear it works but I don't understand your second question

Comment: don't care about second question, i want to ask, if we sent request from client to server, can we use value from client to do something in server, and no need response to server ?

Comment: yes of course, if you *do* need the server reponse, you can send it and process it, if you do not just send the request with data and the server side script will do his job and stay quiet :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a  function ( makeAjaxRequestTo(page) ) that sends an AJAX request to a given page, and then simply call it with a few pages, like this:

```
var pages = [ "/page1/somewhere.php", "/page2/somewhere.php" ];

var page;
for (var i in pages){
    page = pages[i];
    makeAjaxRequestTo(page); // Your own code goes here to send an AJAX request to page x
}
```